# How do I setup Bootstrap SASS/SCSS with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, sass

Bootstrap is already setup with a new ASP.NET project from the default template, but I would like to use the SASS version of Bootstrap so I can customize it, such as altering the font variables.

How do I set this up? Do I need tools like `npm`, `Bower` and `Grunt`? I get a bit lost.

Comment: For anyone doing this today, I don't understand all these crazy answers.  Just pull the npm package "bootstrap" and add the following line to the top of your project's scss file: `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`.  There's documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple so long as you're running Visual Studio 2013 Update 2+ and (I think its needed, not sure) Mads Kristensen's superb Web Essentials add-in.

First, update your Bootstrap NuGet package so it matches, near as possible, the version available on the official Twitter Bootstrap SASS port (they originally write it in LESS and port to SASS).

At the time of writing, NuGet is on 3.3.2 and the SASS port is on 3.3.3, though the tarball says otherwise.

Here's the SASS port on GitHub:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Then remove the following files from you project:

- `\Content\bootstrap.css`
- `\Content\bootstrap.min.css`

Then download the "tar ball" zip from GitHub above and unpack it somewhere. You'll only need the SCSS files, so open the following folder:

`bootstrap-sass-3.3.2.tar\bootstrap-sass-3.3.2\bootstrap-sass-3.3.2\assets\stylesheets`

Copy the `bootstrap` subfolder and stick it in your project `\Content` folder.

Now, add a new item to the `\Content` folder in Visual Studio and choose "SCSS Style Sheet (SASS)" and call it `bootstrap.scss`

It's important to add a new item since it enables the auto-generation stuff, if you just add an existing `.scss` file it doesn't generate/compile the CSS.

Open the new `bootstrap.scss` file and clear it of any default code.

Now go back to your unpacked folder and open the `_bootstrap.scss` file in a Notepad and then copy the contents and paste them into the `bootstrap.scss` file in Visual Studio.

Save the file and it will compile `bootstrap.css`! It will also produce the `.map` file which is used by editors (like Chrome's browser dev tools) to map the gen'ed CSS back to its original SASSy markup. Clever.

Right-click the `.css` file to minify it and choose the option to auto-minify on changes.

Since you've now regenerated the same files as were originally there, your bundles will just work and the site will come up as before.

Oh and to edit your variables, like the fonts, see:

`\Content\bootstrap\_variables.scss`

Comment: Good post. I just wanted to note that when I added the Bootstrap scss package via NuGet it added the /stylesheets folder to my project so I didn't have to download anything from github. VS also managed the minification for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did [here in July of 2019] in Visual Studio 2017;

I installed the *"The Bootstrap Authors, Twitter Inc."* version of  bootstrap.sass (v4.3.1) straight from the `nuget.org` server. I then looked all over the place for info on exactly which file(s) I was going to want to 'compile' from `.scss` to `.css` and finally found this post.

@SandroPaetzold's answer seemed a bit.. excessive / slightly confusing [given how much easier it is to install the package with NuGet], so I decided to write up my process in case it helps anyone who wants to use the SASS version of Bootstrap 4 in their `ASP.Net MVC` project/solution.

I just use Mads K's [WebCompiler](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler), so I had to create the `compilerconfig.json` file [required by the *WebCompiler* tool]. For this I was able to copy it from another project I'd just completed, then made the changes needed for bootstrap, which was to simply compile the `bootstrap.scss` file into my `~/Content` folder. This way, I didn't have to touch the `BundleConfig.cs` file.

(Now, admittedly, if I was going to have more than say, 2-3 .css files, I would have put them into something like `~/Content/css` as I did with that other project I mentioned, but I didn't feel that it was a necessary step in this case.)

So, the entirety of my `compilerconfig.json` was simply:

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "Content/bootstrap.css",
    "inputFile": "Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
    "options": {
      "sourceMap": true
    }
  }
]
```

At this point, I went into the *Task Runner Explorer*, right-clicked on `Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss` (within the left-hand-pane), then selected *Before Build* from the *Bindings* context menu.

Finally, since they're being Built, and thus don't really need to be checked in, I added `Content/*.css` to my `.gitignore` file. (**Note:** Your path may vary.)

This, to my mind, is the least amount of churn for getting this process completed, at least compaired to the other answers. (*Acknowledging that some, if not all of those answers are dealing with other/earlier versions of Bootstrap, and thus may require a bit of extra work.*)

Comment: Not bad but Web Compiler seems to be abandoned by now.

Comment: @eriksan Abandoned or feature-complete? Does it not work with the latest versions of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to be taken to install Bootstrap 4.x with ASP.NET MVC with Visual Studio 2018. I assume you already updated your Bootstrap NuGet package and installed the latest Version of [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/) as mentioned in .

1. [Download Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) and unzip the source files
2. Delete **ALL** Bootstrap CSS files from your `/Content` directory
3. Move the `scss` folder to the `/Content' folder of your project
4. (Optional) Rename `/scss` to `/bootstrap`
5. Compile `bootstrap.scss`
6. Open `AppStart/BundleCongig.cs`
7. Change `~/Content/bootstrap.css` to match the path to your Bootstrap file

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps for ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC in Visual Studio 2017.

- Run `dotnet new mvc`
- Run `git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass`
- Clear contents of `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.min.js`
- Replace contents of `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js` with `GitHub\bootstrap-sass\assets\javascripts\bootstrap.js`
- In VS Solution Explorer, make new folder `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap` and then copy `.js` files from `GitHub\bootstrap-sass\assets\javascripts\bootstrap` into it.
- Copy `GitHub\bootstrap-sass\assets\stylesheets\_bootstrap.scss` to `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css`
- Copy (drag and drop) the whole folder `GitHub\bootstrap-sass\assets\stylesheets\bootstrap` into `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css`
- You need to compile the SASS so you have two options, the first is to assume you're using the full Visual Studio IDE to work on your project, while the second option is to allow Visual Studio and VSCode. You'll also need to consider the situation for CICD pipeline.
- I think the VSCode and CICD setup would require the use of task runners in the IDE across VS, VSCode and perhaps a build step.
- Installing the SASS compiler involves Ruby on Windows and seems to "get complex"; I'm not much of a front-end/JavaScript guy nor Linux lover and favour productivity over fancy fashionable JavaScript tools so I'm going to eschew VSCode support and install the Web Compiler VS extension from Mads Kristensen which hooks into MSBuild, so it should be good for dotnet build when working in VSCode I think, as well as CICD.
- Install Web Compiler (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler).
- Right click  `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\_bootstrap.scss` and choose Web Compiler > Compile File - **Note** the appearance of Scss node in the Task Runner Explorer and the new compilerconfig.json file added to your codebase.
- See the compiled files; configure Git to ignore the minified version.
- Alter the conditional code in `_Layout.cshtml` to point to the minified `_bootstrap.min.css` in production and not the CDN link.
- Run the app and sanity check it, look for requests in the self-host console to the `_bootstrap.css` file and 200 OK returns.
- That's basically it.
- Commit to Git and start making changes to `_variables.scss` etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell in my own project, the npm package "bootstrap" includes all the  SASS files in the folder `node_modules/bootstrap/scss`.  Why in the world would you go through all the work in your answer, and thereby making it a huge pain to pull updates to bootstrap (which are often)??

Comment: +1 - At the time, Bootstrap was made with Less. Today in July 2019 I now use npm to install Bootstrap which contains the SCSS source and Gulp and the gulp-sass npm package to setup tasks to compile into my wwwroot folder.